# Using fmpp in gradle to generate java files

Tags: gradle, freemarker, fmpp

I have an existing maven project which I am attempting to port to gradle.

One sub module uses fmpp/freemarker to generate a whole lot of java files which are then fed back into the build.

I'm new to gradle, and was wondering if anyone knows of an easy way to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

My current pom.xml looks like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Freemarker maven plugin for code generation -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.fmpp-maven-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>fmpp-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.unix4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>unix4j-tools</artifactId>
                    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    <optional>true</optional>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <cfgFile>src/main/resources/codegen/config.fmpp</cfgFile>
                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/main/java</outputDirectory>
                <templateDirectory>src/main/resources/codegen/templates</templateDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src/main/generated</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, should have spent more time googling first.  This is the solution which worked for me:

```
project(':unix4j-core:unix4j-command') {
    configurations {pmd}

    dependencies {
        compile project(':unix4j-core:unix4j-base')
        compile project(':unix4j-tools')
        pmd project(':unix4j-tools')
    }

    task generateFmppSources(dependsOn: ":unix4j-tools:compileJava") << {
        println "Generating sources...."
        ant.taskdef(name:'fmpp', classname:'fmpp.tools.AntTask', classpath:configurations.pmd.asPath);
        ant.fmpp configuration:"src/main/resources/codegen/config.fmpp", sourceRoot:"src/main/resources/codegen/templates", outputRoot:"target/generated-sources/main/java";
    }
    compileJava.dependsOn generateFmppSources
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir 'target/generated-sources/main/java'
            }
        }
    }
}
```